# How to modify the timestamp range of a .pcap file?

Tags: wireshark, pcap, tcpdump, tcpreplay, editcap

## Problem

I need to modify a .pcap file captured over a timespan of 5 minutes such that it simulates a .pcap file captured over a timespan of 20 minutes. The problem is that I don't know how to do this.

### Example

To illustrate the problem, suppose I have a .pcap file with 4 captured packets `p1`-`p4` and `t` as a start time such that:

- `p1` is sent at `t`+ 0 minutes
- `p2` is sent at `t`+ 1 minutes
- `p3` is sent at `t`+ 2 minutes
- `p4` is sent at `t`+ 3 minutes

I want my resulting .pcap file to contain the same four packets but with the timestamps scaled (from 5 minutes to 20 minutes) such that they represent the following:

- `p1` is sent at `t`+ 0 minutes
- `p2` is sent at `t`+ 4 minutes
- `p3` is sent at `t`+ 8 minutes
- `p4` is sent at `t`+ 12 minutes

### Tried solution(s)

- `editcap`, however the only option I could find here is to adjust all timestamps with a set value using the `-t` option.

### Background

I am using `tcpreplay` to replay a scenario in which a user browsers a webpage. I simultaniously inject some packets **which are dependent** on the .pcap file I replayed, i.e. the packets are injected by live monitoring of the replayed traffic and subsequently adjusting the packets it sends out. This entire traffic trace - i.e. both the replayed traffic and the injected packets - are captured using `tcpdump`. As there are a lot of large .pcap files I want to replay, I use the `tcpreplay --multiplier` option to speed up the process. However, this means the final capture is a compressed version of the original .pcap file. I would like to 'stretch' the newly created .pcap to be the same size as the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with Wireshark using its *"Time Shift"* feature.

Assuming the timestamp for packet 1 is `2017-08-17 12:00:00.000000`, select packet 1 then choose *"Edit -> Time Shift..."* and set the time for packet 1 to `2017-08-17 12:00:00.000000` (i.e., don't change this one).  Click the box next to *"...then set packet"* and enter 2 for the packet number and `2017-08-17 12:04:00.000000` as the timestamp.  You'll notice that it also indicates, *"and extrapolate the time for all other packets"*, which is what you want.  Hit *Apply*.

At this point, the timestamps should be adjusted to what you want, although the sub-second component might not end up being exactly the same for all packets and for some reason even packet 1's sub-second component is not *exactly* what was originally specified.  If you really want to retain the original sub-second component, then you'll have to adjust one packet at a time.  Considering that there are only 4 packets to adjust, this should be feasible.  I might suggest filing a [Wireshark bug report](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/) for the erroneous sub-second adjustment though.